# Referring to worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops

So I'm having an issue in referring to a worksheet. I intend to open an input box whenever I find an empty cell on column B throughout the workbook, so I can input and change the empty cell value.
I am, however, getting an error (First was saying subscription out of range and I changed it, so now it says application/ object defined error) on this line:
`For i = 0 To Sheets(j).Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row`

Code:

```
Dim Country As Variant
Dim Capital As Variant
Dim CapitalValue As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
```

`' Select *first line of data*
  Range("B1").Select
  ' Loop to stop when an empty cell is reached.
For j = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    j = ActiveSheet.Index

    Range("B1").Select

    For i = 0 To Sheets(j).Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
        'Select the Country Cell
        ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).Select

        CapitalValue = ActiveCell.Value
            'If Country is empty
            If CapitalValue = "" Then
            MsgBox ("No more Capitals")
            Else
            'Input Capital values
            CapitalValue = ActiveCell.Value
            Country = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
            Capital = InputBox("Capital of " & Country, "Capital Input")
            CapitalValue = Capital
            End If
    Next i
  Next j`

Regards

Comment: I think it's cause you're using I twice  `For i = 0 To Sheets(j).Cells(Rows.Count, <HERE>intColNumber<HERE>).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: The Sheets().Cells() method must have arguments greater than 0. 

`Sheets(j).Cells(Rows.Count, i +1).End(xlUp).Row`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to repeat this across all worksheets (like the `For j = 1 to Worksheets.Count` line would suggest) you shouldn't be changing `j` in the next line to `ActiveSheet.Index`, especially since your code doesn't actually change worksheets at any point.

Your `Range("B1").Select` suggests you want to loop over column B looking for these values, so replace your `For i = 0 To Sheets(j).Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row` with `For i = 1 To Sheets(j).Cells(Sheets(j).Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row` as you need to know where to start with `i`.  I've assumed row 1, but you might need to change that if you have a header row to 2.

You are then selecting the cell `i` rows below the activecell.  For the first time round the loop this will move you from row 2 to row 3.  The second time you will jump from 3 to 5 as i has incremented from 1 to 2.  Best to avoid `Select` in general where possible as it slows things down in any case.  Since you have noted you want to find blank values then prompt the user for the details, I would suggest the following instead:

```
For j = 1 to Worksheets.Count
    For i = 1 To Sheets(j).Cells(Sheets(j).Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        If Sheets(j).Range("B" & i).Value = "" Then
            Country = Sheets(j).Range("A" & i).Value
            Sheets(j).Range("B" & i).Value = InputBox("Please enter the capital for country " & Country, "Capital Input")
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: This works perfectly and it also solved the problem I encountered after (The loop on the empty cells & worksheets). Could I ask you something? Why don't you use the variables name at the "Next" I see that on this case it works both ways. This means you don't actually need to refer them? Thank you @Dave

Comment: I didn't use them as they're not necessary; the code structure will assign the `Next` to the most recent `For` that doesn't have one already, though you can add them if you need to for readability purposes.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your macro, set your sheet to a name like

```
Dim a as worksheet

Set a = Sheets("yoursheetname")
```

Then when you want to refer to that specific sheet just use

```
a.Range("a1").select
```

Assuming your blank values are in column A, I'd do something like

```
Sub findBlanks()
    Dim a As Worksheet
    Set a = Sheets("Sheet1")

    For x = 2 To a.Range("a1048576").End(xlUp).Row 'find last row 
        If a.Range("a" & x).Value = "" Then
            MsgBox ("This cell is blank!!!")
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```